# How to get priority of current job?

Tags: telnet, beanstalkd

In beanstalkd

```
telnet localhost 11300
USING foo
put 0 100 120 5
hello
INSERTED 1
```

How can I know what is the priority of this job when I reserve it? And can I release it by making the new priority equals to **current priority +100**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beanstalkd doesn't return the priority with the data - but you could easily add it as metadata in your own message body. for example, with Json as a message wrapper:

```
{'priority':100,'timestamp':1302642381,'job':'download http://example.com/'}
```

The next message that will be reserved will be the next available entry from the selected tubes, according to priority and time - subject to any delay that you had requested when you originally sent the message to the queue.

**Addition:** You can get the priority of a beanstalk job (as well as a number of other pieces of information, such as how many times it has previously been reserved), but it's an additional call - to the *stats-job* command. Called with the jobId, it returns about a dozen different pieces of information. See the [protocol](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt) document, and your libraries docs.

Comment: ok but how can i release the job with less priority than current one? ie. self::priority +100 for example??? is it possible to modify the contents of job before releasing it??

Comment: No. It returns in priority/time order, from the tubes you are watching.